# Increment a count by JavaScript until reach a given Value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript code to print an auto increment count on the HTML Body. Count is starting from 0 and I increment it by periodic auto click button using setInterval function. I need to stop the count when it reach 10. I used a while loop for auto count function, but when open the page, it is continuously loading and not providing the result. How do I get the Correct result?

JavaScript:

```
var a=0;

function count(){
    a=a+1;
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML=a;
    return true;
}

while (a!=10)
{
    window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
    setInterval(function(){
        button.click();
    },1000);
};
}
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML="Over!";
```

Comment: Browsers have only a single thread to execute JS and update/execute event queue. The `while` loop in the example blocks any other execution, and the interval function is never executed, and button clicks are never detected, hence `a` is not changed, and you've an infinite loop. Wrap everything within `window.onload` handler, and omit the `while` loop, check `a` in the interval function, that way the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable for the interval for later clearing and a check inside of the wanted value is reached.

Then you need a single `onload` event to start the interval and an event for the button, if clicked.

```js
var a = 0,
    interval;

window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        button.click();
    }, 1000);
}

function count() {
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = ++a;
    if (a > 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "Over!";
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="p">--</p>
<button id="clickButton" onclick="count()">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion below

```js
var a=0;
function count(){
    a=a+1;
    if(a<=10) document.getElementById('p').innerHTML=a
}

window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(a<10){
            button.click();
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.getElementById('p').innerHTML="Over!"; 
        }
    },1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="p"></div>
<button id="clickButton" onclick="count()">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable for the interval, and clear it later with `clearInterval`

```js
function buttonAction() {
  var count = 0;
  var idInterval = setInterval(function() {
    let div = document.getElementById("count");
    div.innerHTML+=count;
    count++;
    if (count > 10) {
      clearInterval(idInterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="count">

</div>
<button onClick="buttonAction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things, and you should almost never use setInterval in a while loop.

```js
let a = 0;
const button = document.getElementById('foo');
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (a++ < 10) {
    return button.click();
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);

button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(a));
```

```html
<button id="foo">
Button
</button>
```